# Solr Suggestion with multiple payloads

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using Solr suggester feature for **businessName** lookup. As user enters the query, along with the matched names, we want solr to send other attributes from profile like id, address, city, state, country etc. fields.

I tried to configure multiple fields in solr suggester using **payloadField** tag but it is returning only the first field. I have tried putting them in comma separated fashion, but no luck. Here is the current config from **solrconfig.xml** file.

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">businessName</str>
        <str name="payloadField">profileId</str> 
        <str name="payloadField">email</str>
        <str name="payloadField">city</str>
        <str name="payloadField">state</str>
        <str name="payloadField">postalCode</str>
        <str name="payloadField">phoneNumber</str>
        <str name="weightField">businessName</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="preserveSep">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

What configuration is required to send multiple payloads in result? Thanks.

---

**Edit:**
This is current output of the solr suggester.

```
    {
        "suggest": {
            "suggest": {
                "Rock": {
                    "numFound": 1,
                    "suggestions": [
                        {
                            "term": "Rockview Properties",
                            "weight": 0,
                            "payload": "123456789"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Expectation:**
A way in which suggester payload contains more than one field. The payload field also contain the information that **what data belongs to which field**. I am not looking for copying all the data in a single field using `copyField` tag and then passing as payload approach.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your output as it looks now? And also what are you expecting in your output?

Comment: I dont think thats the function of a payload. Here is an article explaining payloads in detail. https://lucidworks.com/blog/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/

Comment: New URL: https://lucidworks.com/post/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been doing online reading and search for the issue, sending multiple payload while returning solr suggester results. I found that, **we can send only one field as payload from our index**.

Reference: [Link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SOLR-suggester-with-highlighting-td4114454.html)

**Further suggestions are welcome.**