# Returning price and thumbnail info from solr suggester

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I am using the solr (6.5.1) suggester to return autocomplete results.
I am trying to display a price and a thumbnail with the autocomplete results but can't find a way to do this.

Is there a way to return more fields?

I see these two questions from two years ago that seem to be trying to accomplish what I want, and both say that at the time it is not doable.

[Solr Suggestion with multiple payloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434186/solr-suggestion-with-multiple-payloads)

[Returning an entire Document on Solr Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968780/returning-an-entire-document-on-solr-suggestion)

Has anything changed since two years ago?

Is there a different way that this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put all info you need into a field, and use that field as payload. For example you could:

1. append some string info, separated by |: payload:"17|/path/to/thumbnail"
2. or you could use Solr BinaryField and put a Java pojo containing the info you need there serialized

I would go the simple route, the first one.

Comment: Exactly this. Most of the time, when your requirement calls for a complex query, flip it around so you store the data exactly as you need it, and keep the query simple.